# CorePlot iPhone error : CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: no such file or directory

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-plot

I'm trying to walk someone through adding CorePlot to their iPhone app.  I have it working on my computer, but he keeps getting the

```
CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: no such file or directory
```

error.  I get the same error if I mess up the "header search paths" in the build settings.  Otherwise, I can build it just fine.  The only difference in our setup is that I'm using XCode 3.2.3 and he is using a previous version.  Would that cause an issue like this?  The only thing I can think of is that his header search path is not getting read correctly, because we've verified that the header search path is correct on his end.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that in the build target, the header is part of the copy build phase. This should clear it up if you're in fact, embedding CorePlot in the application.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. We are not copying any files to the bundle, just referencing. I get the same errors he does in my project if I set the header search path incorrectly. If I set them correctly I build the project fine. I think he has the header search path wrong

Comment: Hi,

I am getting the error " CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: No such file or directory". I have kept the coreplot0.2.2 folder in the desktop. I used the following path for set header path. 
"/Users/Giri/Desktop/iPhoneGraph/CorePlot 0.2.2/Source/framework".

is it correct ? please Help Me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

- You should to set **Header Search Paths = ../build/ ** ../framework/ ****
- Your filepaths should be:

  -> folder X

  -> -> build     (CorePlot buildFolder)

  -> -> framework (CorePlot projectFolder)

  -> -> myProjectFolder

  -> -> -> myProject.xcodeproj

  -> -> -> [...]

Comment: Hi,

I am getting the error " CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: No such file or directory". I have kept the coreplot0.2.2 folder in the desktop. I used the following path for set header path. 
"/Users/Giri/Desktop/iPhoneGraph/CorePlot 0.2.2/Source/framework".

is it correct ? please Help Me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"${PROJECT_DIR}/Project Name/CorePlot_0.9/Source/framework"`

Comment: It's unbelievable how inconvenient and implicit core plot integration is

Answer (score 2):

Go thru this link..

http://www.jaysonjc.com/programming/pie-chart-drawing-in-iphone-using-core-plot-library.html

It'll b helpful..

just check the header search paths (to get the right path ,go to CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h file ,right click and then get info )and even U should tick on recursive in header search paths.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have dragged the headers folder which is the part of the framework. For me just by just by dragging the solution did not help. I had to drag the headers to my application in order to make it work.