# Classic problem: CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h : No such file or directory

Tags: iphone, core-plot

Please excuse me for asking this old problem but I have really tried 
every solutions I could find in this forum and over at stackoverflow, 
and the problem still hasn't been resolved...Please help me :( 
So here is what I did:

1) I downloaded 'CorePlot 0.2.2.zip' into my project folder.

2) Drag and drop the 'CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj' into my project. 
Uncheck the "Copy items..." and change "Relative to project".

3) Drag 'libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a' to Target's 'Link Binary with 
Libraries" folder.

4) Add 'CorePlot-CocoaTouch (from CorePlot ...)' under Direct 
Dependencies.

5) 5) In 'Header search paths' I added path- /Users/el08ywk/Desktop/ 
PlotGraphhhhh/CorePlot 0.2.2/Source/framework , and set it to 
'recursive'.

6) In "other linker flags", I added -ObjC and -all_load

7) Finally, I added the QuartzCore framework to my project.

Now when i build and run it, i have 51 errors, all of which say 
something is 'undeclared' and in .h file says Coreplot-CocoaTouch no 
such file or directory...

So where have i done wrong?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Error : " CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: No such file or directory" while implementing Core-Plot in iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037368/getting-error-coreplot-cocoatouch-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-impleme)

Comment: See also [CorePlot iPhone error : CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: no such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481662/coreplot-iphone-error-coreplot-cocoatouch-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 2):

> "5) 5) In 'Header search paths' I
>   added path- /Users/el08ywk/Desktop/
>   PlotGraphhhhh/CorePlot
>   0.2.2/Source/framework , and set it to 'recursive'."

Be careful where you download and use de core-plot library, I had some troubles when it was on my Desktop, try to move the folder at "/" to test first, and after you are sure it works, put it where you have sufficient authorizations.

I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the CorePlot framework has not been added to build target.  A project can build many targets at once each with it's own set of dependencies. Check the frameworks added to the target. Most likely CorePlot won't be there.

Comment: I couldn't find the CorePlot.framework. And I don't think it's needed, not at least according to this instruction anyway- http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications

Comment: Actually, the instructions tell you exactly how to add the framework to a <i>target</i> after the framework has been added to the <i>project</i>. Control click the target and choose Add->Existing Framework. CorePlot should show on the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, I have got it fixed days ago. apparently /Users/el08ywk/Desktop/ PlotGraphhhhh/CorePlot**-**0.2.2/Source/framework  was broken without that bolded character, so its simply folder naming problem breaking up the path... silly me  :\