# error: CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: No such file or directory

Tags: iphone, ios4, graphics, graph, core-plot

i know i am asking the same question as this question is already ask many times by other people but still i have problem after following all steps

First, drag the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj file into your iPhone application's Xcode project (making sure that nothing's copied and the paths are relative to your project). Then go to the Targets tab in Xcode, select your application's target, and bring up the inspector. Go to the General settings page and add the CorePlot-CocoaTouch library as a direct dependency.

Core Plot is built as a static library for iPhone, so you'll need to drag the libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a static library from under the CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj group to your target's Link Binary With Libraries folder.

You'll also need to point to the right header location. Under your Build settings, set the Header Search Paths to the relative path from your application to the framework/ subdirectory within the Core Plot source tree. Make sure to make this header search path recursive. You need to add -ObjC and -all_load to Other Linker Flags as well.

Core Plot is based on Core Animation, so if you haven't already, add the QuartzCore framework to your application project.

i am not able to figure it out where is the problem

thank you

Comment: Mostly this error comes because you not set proper Header Search Path.

Comment: /Users/Kawapoo/CorePlot/Source/framework/... this is my header serach path

Comment: you get it from right clicking on Core Plot SDK there you find full path

Comment: possible duplicate of [CorePlot iPhone error : CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: no such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481662/coreplot-iphone-error-coreplot-cocoatouch-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: See also [Classic problem: CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h : No such file or directory…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119438/classic-problem-coreplot-cocoatouch-h-no-such-file-or-directory) and [Getting Error : “ CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h: No such file or directory” while implementing Core-Plot in iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037368/getting-error-coreplot-cocoatouch-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-impleme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added header folder in my project

Comment: ya, and now i can use this for generating graphs

Comment: i was following all steps which are describe in xcode-documentation and it was give me an error then i read text file which is in installing package and their they state that copy "head folder" in to your project.. i did and its working fine

Comment: what do you mean by copying head folder into your project

Answer (score 0):

try this link, this will help you.

https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-12836

Comment: I think your answer would look much better if you would give a (brief) summary what that link is about. You know "here link will help" is exactly how answers should not look like ...